# Function which prints pattern

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm stuck. I need to figure out certain function which should print "*****".

For instance:

If the parameter is 5 it should print  (five) ***** , if the parameter is 3 it should print (three) *** etc.

```
function line(n) {
  return n; 
} 

console.log(line(5));
```

I'm very grateful for any answers. :)

Comment: look into string.slice or use a for loop

Comment: Hint: you need to use loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with a loop. It will work until the `n`. See the comments in the code.

```js
function line(n) {
  var stars = ''; // Declare an empty string
  
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){ // Loop until i is less than n;
     stars += '*'  ;  // add * to the stars in every iteration
  }
  
  return stars; // return stars
} 

console.log(line(5));
console.log(line(3));
```

Comment: This is obvious homework - you give the solution too easily

Comment: This isn't a homework, it's a task and I don't solve it yet. The solution above works but it isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array and use `.fill` to fill default values and `join` to get a string value.

```js
function line(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill('*').join('');
} 

console.log(line(5));
console.log(line(3));
```

**Note:** `Array.fill` is not supported by old browsers. Please check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility) before using.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
function line(n) {
  return '*'.repeat(n);
} 

console.log(line(5));
console.log(line(3));
```

Comment: No support for IE [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Rajesh True. This may or may not be relevant. But nice to know anyways.

Comment: @Rajesh Same applies for `Array.fill`, it seems.

Comment: Oops! I didn't see that coming. I have added a caveat about it. Thanks